# Docusign API - Multi-language

Tags: docusignapi

I want to use the Docusign API to get documents signed in Italian.  I don't see anywhere in the docs where this is supported in the API.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want the signing page to in Italian language?

Comment: Yes, the signng frame should be in Italian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing ceremony will automatically be in Italian if a particular signer has their web browser locale set for Italian.

Try it out.